# Firebase security rules to read specific items only

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to using Firebase and feel myself completely lost with DB rules. I need to allow users to read items that have owner field equal to specific value.

This is the records structure I have:

```
{
  "books" : {
    "-LKwbZsfy55d24kwX4tf" : {
      "description" : "Adventures",
      "title" : "Captain Donsak",
      "owner" : "b7bS753Hvc0fmQ24Jnc"
    },
    "-LKwc1Xna07nequDtpF6" : {
      "description" : "History",
      "title" : "World War II",
      "owner" : "hLoOnnv4883Vhvm9Vt4"
    },
    "-LKwi4qcsqbgvZPdhCXp" : {
      "description" : "Adventures",
      "title" : "Sea Wolf",
      "owner" : "umV4hFm96vpdwBytx63"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried several options of rules, including following (these were provided in firebase docs), but in any case it returns 0 items when I apply any of these rules.

```
{
  "rules": {     
    "books": {
        ".read": "data.child('owner').val() === 'umV4hFm96vpdwBytx63'",
        ".write": "auth != null"   
    }
  }
}


{
  "rules": {     
    "books": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "root.child('owner').val() == 'umV4hFm96vpdwBytx63'",
        ".write": "auth != null"   
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

If I just specify

```
".read": "auth != null"
```

it returns all records, but this is not what I need.

I use a simple js command to read the data:

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('books');
```

Basically what I need is to filter data using security rules, but this is not possible as stated by RenaudTarnec below. So I'll have to use js to filter it:

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('owner').equalTo(owner);
```

Please advise what could be wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: your rules say check if the owner equals your hardcoded uid

Comment: use `auth.uid` instead of `'umV4hFm96vpdwBytx63'`

Comment: Can you please [edit] that information into your question? Not everyone reads comments and to help us help you it is best to make your question as complete as possible :)

Comment: @AndréKool, added this info to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually "Firebase rules are not filters", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

It means that, to fetch this data, you have to use a query that is "aligned" with your security rules.

Like the following in JavaScript, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('owner').equalTo('umV4hFm96vpdwBytx63');
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question I think we really need to see the code being used first. At first look both rules in the answer seem to be incorrect to me (first checks child of books instead of books/booID and second checks child of the root)

Comment: Thank you @Renaud Tarnec, this is what I was looking for actually. Basically I needed to filter data based on security rules. I was considering js filtering, but the it looks not secure to me. I would prefere to filter the records on server, rather than on client. But if it's the only possible approach, I will chose it. Maybe I have to restructure my records to make it more secure... have to think.

Comment: @Liu I think it would be helpful for you if you take a look at [query based security rules](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html). [Also here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules).

Comment: @AndréKool, thank you! Query based rules look promising. I'll try this out and will respond back with the results.

Comment: @AndréKool, query based security rules  work great for my case. As a result I have used queries in security rules and in js file:
{
  "rules": {     
    "books": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'owner' && query.equalTo == auth.uid",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}

const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('owner').equalTo(owner);

Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Liu Nice to hear that. If your solution is different from the ones provided here already would you consider posting it as an answer so other people can also benefit from it?

Answer (score 3):

According to @AndréKool suggestion, this is how I solved this question:
In order to filter the response items, I used [query based security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules):

```
{ 
  "rules": { 
      "books": { 
          ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'owner' && query.equalTo == auth.uid", 
          ".write": "auth != null" 
        } 
     } 
  }
```

And I use a js filtering accordingly:

`const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('books').orderByChild('owner').equalTo(owner);`

Thanks everyone for your help!  ;-)

Comment: You shoud probably accept your own answer, since it is THE one that corresponds to your solution.

Comment: I can accept my own answer in 2 days. Will accept later. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
{
  "rules": {     
    "books": {
      ".read": "data.child('owner').val() === auth.uid",
      ".write": "auth != null"   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question (or I did). It clearly states the owner needs to be _"equal to specific value"_ and not the uid.

Comment: Got it. Another suggestion: Does `data` means the child `-LKwi4qcsqbgvZPdhCXp` or the root `books`

Comment: it doesn't work because data means `books` which doesn't have a child called `owner`

Comment: Yeah, the specific owner value is not the key here. Apologies if my question was not clear enough. The main issue is I wanted to filter the records and return only those matching specific owner (either auth.uid or specific string). This can be done in js code only, not via security rules.