# Safety of using token claims in Firestore client side and grouping notifications

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have already and app which is developed by Ionic-Angular and have a REST API which is developed by Nodejs and Mongodb. After hearing about Firebase, I decided to redevelop it by that.

In my old app, I used a **single DB for all customers** and seperate them and their data that they can read and write by a **groupId**.

I save their groupId in their jwt token and send it in the request header to the backend. In the backend I will get this groupId and filter requested data by that groupId, or when they post or put data, I also check and use this groupId. In this case they are able just to see or change the data of their group. Also I send message by Socket.io to that specific group to update their data and have real time data.

My questions about the new app (Firebase) are:

1. Is it safe to set and get data by the group_id which I get from user token in Firestore client side? (I don't like to use API because I don't have real time data anymore). Is user able to change the group_id and get the data of other groups?
2. Firebase notifies all users about the changes and refresh their data to get the updates and they have real time data. In my case, I need to update the data of the specific group which its data is changed. Is it possible to do that or all users in all groups always refresh their data when changes occur in DB?

EDITED:

Here is the code sample. 
I need to know if a malicious user can change the value I send in "where".
If yes, how can I secure if with firebase rules for reading data?

```
    loadAllUnits(): Observable<Unit[]> {                      
        return this.db.collection(
            'units',
                ref => ref.orderBy("name")
                .where('groupId', '==', this.authService.currentUser.value.groupId)
            )            
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(snaps => convertSnaps<Unit>(snaps)));
    }
```

Comment: Answer to your first question is below. The second question sounds possible, but is quite a bit too broad to answer in its current form. I'd recommend trying to implement it, and posting back with a more concrete question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `group_id` as a custom claim in the Firebase Authentication ID token, it can only be put in there by someone who has access to the administrative credentials of the project for which that ID token is minted. There is no way for a user to change its value based on the client-side API, or the configuration information required for the client-side SDKs.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Actually I know that user cannot change it in the token. But what if in the place I send it as a parameter, the user send something else? For writing data I can compare the check it with rules in the backend. But for reading data I have no idea how to implement this rules.

Comment: All Firebase services that integrate with Authentication decode the ID token, and verify that it's properly signed, before using any of its data. There's no way for a user to inject any information into this process without them having access to your project credentials. If you're thinking of another process, please edit your question to show how that would work. Preferably in code, as I find it hard to parse what the malicious user would do from your description so far.

Comment: Hello, the question is edited. With example, maybe you understand better what I mean.

Comment: You can check the filter in the server-side security rules against the value of the custom claim in their token. So something along the lines of `resource.data.groupId == request.auth.token.groupId` (I didn't run this, so please check carefully against docs and simulator).

Comment: I red somewhere that I cannot filter data by security rules. But I will try this and let you know. thank you for your time.

Comment: Security rules don't filter data indeed, so you'll have to have that check both in your query and the security rules. The security rules check the query to see if it is allowed.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094260/firebase-security-rules-to-read-specific-items-only